# inserting own image on excel through c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, excel-2007

Hi i have the following code... where i generate my own image and paste in to excel worksheet, please can you tell me why its background color is always BLUE? is it possible somehow to change that for example to make it transparent or white? (i tried flag.MakeTransparent(); but it also does not work)

```
       Bitmap flag = new Bitmap(200,200);
       using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(flag))
        {
            g.DrawString("N", new Font("Verdana", 80, FontStyle.Bold), 
                         new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(40, 30));
        }
       System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(flag, true);
       ws.Paste(range, Type.Missing);
```

when i use the following

```
       flag.Save("C:\\image.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

the image.png has transparent background...

thanks a lot!

Comment: Need more info here, how do you make the image? Is it just that new Bitmap(200, 200) or do you do more stuff? Also is the image background blue or the spreadsheet?

Comment: image background when it is pasted on the excel worksheet is BLUE, it is only new Bitmap(200,200)...

Comment: Try pasting the image into mspaint to see how it looks? If it is not with blue background, it could be that the image when pasted in excel is selected - try unselecting it.

Comment: you mean to copy the image already pasted on excel worksheet? if that's so, i copied it and pasted to mspaint still background is BLUE, i deselected the image it is still BLUE...

Comment: No. What I mean is, after your statement Clipboard.SetDataObject(flag, true); executes, paste the image into Paint & see how it looks. If it has blue background, the problem could be with the image.

Comment: hi shahkalpesh, i did paste it into paint it still has BLUE background...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is answer to an old post, but in case anyone else finds it on google (like I did):

The bmp does not contain background information, therefore it has to be converted:

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
IDataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
dataObject.SetData("PNG", false, ms);
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, false);

The solution is copied from this address, where the full solution is:
http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.drawing&tid=64a90f25-9dd5-4d27-8d69-02993d0a35ed&cat=en_US_fa599017-a9ec-4987-b602-c19ba8e5a4da&lang=en&cr=US&sloc=&p=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filling the image first thing?

```
 Image i = new Bitmap(200, 200);
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(i);
 g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, 0, 0, 200, 200);
```